# 360° lecker. Bedeutung dieser Bäckereiwerbung

Tags: meaning

Was bedeutet

> 360° lecker

auf den Papiertüten gewisser Bäckerei (aus Deutschland)? Mehr Kontext gibt es leider nicht.

*Edit*. Unter *360 Grad lecker* kann man lesen, was als ich die Frage stellte nicht hatte:

> Egal ob Apfeltasche, Laugenstange oder Snack des Monats: Jeder Griff ein Volltreffer.

Nach der Antwort sehe ich, dass das nicht unwichtig war.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich würde (allerdings ins Blaue hinein) annehmen, dass 360 Grad hier als Synonym gemeint sein könnte für

> rundum

Also *Rundum lecker* - was nach einem halbwegs akzeptablen Werbespruch klingt. Während *360 Grad lecker* ein bisschen maniriert ist. Nunja.

Allenfalls könnte man noch vermuten (oder hoffen), dass der Name der Firma vielleicht auch etwas mit der durch die 360 Grad eingeführten Geometriethematik zu tun hat. Zum Beispiel hätte der Spruch einigermaßen Witz, wenn der Bäcker mit Familiennamen Kreis oder von mir aus Kreiß hieße:

> Bäckerei Kreiß - 360 Grad lecker.

Oder auch:

> Bäckerei Winckelmann: 360 Grad lecker.

Aber solche Kontextinformation hast du uns leider nicht mitgegeben.

#### Miszelle

Ich darf auf dem Wege der Assoziation noch berichten, dass es in meiner Heimatstadt einen recht großen Bäcker namens Keim gibt, der auf seinen Lieferfahrzeugen den Werbespruch *Allen schmeckt, was Keim bäckt* spazierenträgt. Der Volksmund hat daraus aber spöttisch

> Keim schmeckt, was Keim bäckt

gemacht. Wozu man natürlich wissen muss, dass *keim* die dort verbreitete alltagsschludrige Aussprache von *keinem* ist.

(Nun hat es dieser Spruch also auch noch ins Internet gebracht.)

Comment: Und wieviele Keime enthalten die Erzeugnisse dieser Bäckerei so im Regelfall?

Comment: Ich denke es spielt auch auf Temperatur/Ofen an, wobei 360° aber ein wenig heiß ist - zumindest in der Küche gehen die Öfen nur bis 250°C o.s.ä.

Comment: Das war Wiener Feinbäcker. Aber tatsächlich hätte es geholfen, wenn ich bei der Fragestellung über die vollständige Werbung-Information hätte verfügen können (leider konnte ich mich nur an die *360 Grad* erinnern).

Comment: @userunknown - Ich kenne kein Gebäck, das bei 360 Grad gebacken würde. (Bei Pizza im Holzofen könnte man nochmals genauer hinschauen.) Allerdings: Wenn der Bäcker *Fahrenheit* heißen sollte, ergäbe es wieder Sinn: 360 Grad Fahrenheit entsprechen 180 Grad Celsius, und das ist eine sehr typische Backtemperatur. Also: ***Bäckerei Fahrenheit - 360 Grad lecker***.